# Polymer 3 ide - template editting

Tags: javascript, polymer

What are people using for editting templates in Polymer 3? I've tried both intelliJ and vscode (along with their respective plugins) and in both cases I get no syntax highlighting or autocomplete for content within the backticks of `static get template() { return html``}`.

Do I just have things configured incorrectly? What are others using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use visual studio code and the following extensions to achieve this:

- lit-html
- Template Literal Editor

As a side note I have also found the following extensions to be very helpful when developing polymer apps:

- Import Cost (amazing extension that provides info on the size of your imports)
- Polymer IDE
- Polymer Snippets
- Polymer Syntax

Comment: This makes it so much better (lit html)! Thank You

Answer (score 1):

### IntelliJ

Regarding the JetBrains family, Language Injections capability handles automatically code assistance inside template literals. This should also work in IntelliJ. If you set up everything correctly ([see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-language-injections.html)) and it still doesn't work, try to manually inject html in you template literals by placing the cursor between the backticks, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and selecting *Inject language or reference* > *HTML*.

Note that for web projects you might also consider using [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) instead of IntelliJ.

### VSCode

VSCode doesn't handle automatically template literals code injection but for your case there are:

- A lit-html [syntax highlighting plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.lit-html)
- A lit-html [IntelliSense TypeScript plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript-lit-html-plugin)